# Linq to SQL adding IN Equivalent

Tags: sql, linq

I have this query which works fine

```
var badWords = _db.Restrictions.Where(x => x.Value.Length == 4 && x.Status_ID == 1 && x.RestrictionType.Status_ID == 1);
```

Now I am trying to add a query to check if my type ID is withing a certain id list as follows

```
var idlist = new int[] { 28,24,16,13,14,15 };
var badWords = _db.Restrictions.Where(x => x.Value.Length == 4 && x.Status_ID == 1 && x.RestrictionType.Status_ID == 1 && idlist.Contains(x.RestrictionType)  );
```

But getting an error under the contains

Error   5   'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What's the `Type` of `x.RestrictionType`, I strongly suspect it's not an `int`? If it's an enum, try explicitly casting: `... && idlist.Contains((int)x.RestrictionType)`

Comment: @chridam if you look at the question, it is actually an entity - the original version tests a sub-property

Comment: @MarcGravell True, so there won't be any need for the `x.RestrictionType.Status_ID == 1` comparison but to include `1` in `idlist` if that's the case?

Comment: @chridam indeed; frankly, until the OP clarifies exactly **what** about the `.RestrictionType` they intend to compare, I expect we can only guess

Comment: @MarcGravell Yup, we can only speculate indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single-value status test

```
&& x.RestrictionType.Status_ID == 1
```

indicates that `RestrictionType` is a sub-object; presumably, then, you are trying to test against specific instances of restriction-type:

```
&& idlist.Contains(x.RestrictionType.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 var badWords = _db.Restrictions.Select(x => x.Id).Except(idlist);
 badWords=badWords.Where(x => x.Value.Length == 4 && x.Status_ID == 1 && x.RestrictionType.Status_ID == 1 );
```

Comment: While this code may help solve the problem, a code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain what the code does, where it gets inserted, why this approach was chosen, and link to relevant documentation.